# ckeditor outside admin panel - django 3.1

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor based on instructions in [Django CKEditor — Django CKEditor 5.3.1 documentation](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

it works just fine in the admin panel.

But outside the admin panel, I want to add it to a message section.

`settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'ckeditor',
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cms/static')
]

# MEDIA Folder Settings

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# CKEditor path
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = False
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
```

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

`base_site.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}
<script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/';</script>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

To use it outside the admin panel I added the following configs.

`models.py`:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
class Contact(models.Model):
    message = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

in `base.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/styles/default.min.css">

{% block content %}  {% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.1/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

In a html file(`contacts.html`):

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
<div class="col-md-8" >

          <h3 class="mt-3"> New Message </h3>
          <hr>

          <form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}        
            
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-10 ml-auto">
                                <textarea   name="message" 
                                            id="message" 
                                            class="form-control" 
                                            required  ></textarea>
                                <input disabled></input>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Submit button -->
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-block" 
                              type="submit"
                              style="background: #b5b5b5;">
                              Send
                      </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
          </form>

</div>
```

although I added those js files. but it doesn't render the CKEditor outside the admin panel.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this in your contacts.html

```
<script>
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
 CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
 CKEDITOR.config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
</script>
```

Comment: than add this also <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.0/full/ckeditor.js"></script>

Comment: No. do you think I miss some js file? I added the files in `base.html` which extends in `contacts.html`.

Comment: no did not say taht you miss i am just helping.If you add these two things it will work becouse i am using ckeditor and it worked for me.

Comment: it's almost 5 hours I'm trying to fix it. but it doesn't work for me! thank you for your time.

Comment: in `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );` what is `'editor1'`? its id or name of a text field?

Comment: it is name to given textarea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225352/discussion-between-shahriar-m-and-ankit).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not actual for you, but just 30 mins ago I face with the same problem.

This way didn't work for me:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

But this one works:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

So, I just added {{ form.media }}.